# Launch Google Navigation without routes choosing

Tags: android, google-maps

I am launching Google Navigation with intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + mCity));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

It build route from my current location to destination city. But sometimes it give me few routes. Is there way to force give me always only one route?

Answer (score 0):

*It is just launching Google Navigation app with destination and current address, so it will       depend on user to choose one route as is case with regular navigation app.*

Comment: You mean I need to specify saddr=MyLocation? It doesn't helps. Google Navigations built few routes and suggest me to choose one.